# How do you update links in excel based on specific text in the link using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

How do you update links in excel based on specific text in the link using VBA?
Using Office 2016

I have 40 locations with independent servers for each location.

All of the file names are the same at each location and saved in the same folder with only the location name being different.

For example:

```
Store 1\Schedules\2017\04_01_17.xlxb
Store 2\Schedules\2017\04_01_17.xlxb
Store 3\Schedules\2017\04_01_17.xlxb
```

Each location has a schedule for each week of the year as well as several previous years.

The issue is that the Master recap file that reaches out to each one of these files has to be manipulated currently by editing links one at a time if I wanted to retrieve data for only the 04_01_17 week.

If the entire file was to be enabled it would pull every linked file for the entire year and several previous years and take hours to complete.

What I was looking for was VBA code that would ask for text that is contained in the link and would pull all files that matched.

For Example

```
"Contains" 
Answer=04_01_17
```

Thanks in Advance

Brad

Answer (score 0):

These two subroutines below show you how to view / manipulate links in a file.
The key part you are looking for is `ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)` to get an array with the list of links, and `ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink` to ... change the link.

```
Sub gen_links()
aLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
If Not IsEmpty(aLinks) Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(aLinks)
        MsgBox "Link " & i & ":" & Chr(13) & aLinks(i)
    Next i
End If
End Sub

Sub swap_links1()
aLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
If Not IsEmpty(aLinks) Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(aLinks)
    If aLinks(i) = "C:\tests\2017(1)\Test1.xlsx" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink "C:\tests\2017(1)\Test1.xlsx", "C:\tests\2017(2)\Test2.xlsx", xlExcelLinks
    End If
    If aLinks(i) = "C:\tests\2017(2)\Test2.xlsx" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink "C:\tests\2017(2)\Test2.xlsx", "C:\tests\2017(1)\Test1.xlsx", xlExcelLinks
    End If
    MsgBox "Link " & i & ":" & Chr(13) & aLinks(i)
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

[ChangeLink documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836537.aspx)
[LinkSources documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821922.aspx)

You can utilise this by building an if-test for every possible option, or more sensibly, creating a variable and doing an if-not-test. E.g.

```
My_Store_Name = "Store 1"
My_Year_Name = "2017"
My_File_Name = "04_01_17"
My_Test_file = My_Store_Name & "\Schedules\"  & My_Year_Name & "\" & My_File_Name & ".xlxb"
If aLinks(i) <> My_Test_file Then
```

Comment: I tried both sub listed above. Each one gave me a pop up with the store changing each time. But nothing updated, i needed to hit "Ok" 40 times to get through all of the locations. I ran this on a test file that was only looking at one file per location. If I had ran it on the master file I believe that it would of required me to select "OK" for ever location and ever link within the file. Looking for a way for the file to ask which file needs to be updated.

Comment: The examples are provided *as examples*. You are meant to adapt the code for your own purposes. Links to the official documentation has been provided for you to follow up on. You asked how to update links - answered. You asked how to test for which links need to be updated - answered. If you now also want to know how to get user input, there are many different ways to do this, and would be question 3 of 3 - which I have already partially answered in the second part of my answer by showing you how to build a test string.

Comment: For example, you could have the location stored in a cell in a worksheet, in which case My_file_name would point to a cell reference. You could include a form control in a worksheet, in which case the variable would point to the control. You could use an inputbox (similar to the msgbox in the example) to pop-up and get the name. On-the-fly user interaction is a complex issue and you need to be very specific as to how you are looking to achieve this.